# Three.js canvas renderer seams between polygons

Tags: three.js

I'm already feeling comfortable enough with this library, but this one made me tired already:

When I'm trying to simply render a mesh without any textures, exported from blender to .obj (triangulating, smoothing groups enabled), the WebGL renderer does that perfectly, but I also need to make it possible with canvas renderer, and here comes the trouble; polygon edges have seams between them and become partially seen through

Just to make it clear, providing screenshots

WebGL Renderer
https://www.monosnap.com/image/OVaQO8yLDU9Wl6ufhADDVCEWg

Canvas renderer
https://www.monosnap.com/image/1AYeyHjWkGx9fQ6vg6xLr0EcV

mesh is quite complex, ~7k triangles

Comment: Can you provicde a live example of _your_ code?

Comment: Sure, there you go

http://mt-arms.com/aktuning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `CanvasRenderer`, you need to set

```
material.overdraw = 0.5; // or some number between 0 and 1
```

This will help to alleviate the problem.

Note: `overdraw` used to be a boolean; it is now a float.

three.js r.63

Comment: this doesn't work, still got seams.

loader code:

`var loader2 = new THREE.OBJLoader();
      loader2.load( 'models/cevje.obj', function(object) {
       object.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, shading:THREE.FlatShading, overdraw:0.5});
       sceneobjectparent2.add(object);
      });`

Comment: just the same code as here
[<link>](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_lights_pointlights.html)

Comment: Are you using three.js version r.63?

Comment: I was on r62, no difference after updating to r63

Comment: You are assigning a Lambert material to the loaded object, instead of to the object's child mesh. Do this: `object.children[0].material.overdraw = 0.5;`

Comment: Now this one almost solves the problem, except for partial see-through polygons - but this must be the problem with canvas z-sorting.

Thank you!