# I Need to hide edges on ThreeJS box primitive

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, edges

I need to hide the edges that are displayed in a box primitive using ThreeJS. These only are drawn when I put a texture on the faces.

I've tried with many options like wireframe=false, but the edges are still drawn.

This is the code:

```
        var container, stats;
        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var canvasWidth = 500; 
        var canvasHeight = 500;
        var windowHalfX = 100;
        var windowHalfY = 100;

        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );

        // Camera
        camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( canvasWidth / - 2, canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2, canvasHeight / - 2, - 500, 5000 );

        // Scene
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        camera.position.x = 200;
        camera.position.y = 200;
        camera.position.z = 200;

        camera.lookAt( scene.position );

        // Renderer
        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor( "#fff" );
        renderer.setSize( canvasWidth, canvasHeight );

        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var size = 100;
        geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( size, size, size ); 

        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
            color: "#0000ff", 
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            wireframe: false
        });

        // Comment this line to paint a single color cube
        material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Color_icon_black.png") });

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( mesh );

        var draw = function() {
            requestAnimationFrame( draw );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

        draw();
```

And a link to the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gyss/qg4x9/

Cheers!

Comment: The fiddle doesn't seem to work? Can you clarify what

>I need to remove the vertices that are displayed in a box primitive using ThreeJS. These only are drawn when I put a texture on the faces.

If you remove one vertex, you will most likely remove half of your box. Also, most likely, you will have to remove the indecis and other attributes. I bet you need something else.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the mistake. I meant to remove (or don't paint) the white edges you can see in the example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199721/three-js-canvas-renderer-seams-between-polygons/20200185#20200185

Comment: Thanks WestLangley, I've just tested few minutes ago the WebGLRenderer and solved the problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem changing this line

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```

for this other

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

Other possible solution, as WestLangley commented above is to use this line with CanvasRenderer

```
material.overdraw = 0.5; // or some number between 0 and 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();`
to remove the edges, a parameter (`overdraw:true`) needs to be added to the material definition like this:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: true } );
```

Then you can use add the material to the 3D object:

```
mesh = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( geometry, material );
```

Comment: "var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { overdraw: true } );"


without the map:texture