# ThreeJs Textures Stretching In Corner

Tags: three.js, textures

I have a problem with textures in threejs, I textured a cube like so:

```
    var boxtexv = boxtex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("boxtex.png");
    var boxtex= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: boxtexv});
```

And this seems to work, but if I look at the cube from certain angles, The texture stretches from the corner to the center, could anybody explain this and help me?

PS: I am using CanvasRenderer.

Comment: See if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709866/threejs-cube-texture-strange-visual/16720261#16720261

Comment: It helped a little bit, but now the texture is still stretching from parts of the sides, and in general it looks choppy. EDIT: I increased the numbers and it fixed the texture, but now there are little white lines (forming triangles) all over the cube, can I fix those?

Comment: See if this answers your 2nd question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199721/three-js-canvas-renderer-seams-between-polygons/20200185#20200185